# Shrink LVM2 Thin Volume

Tags: lvm, scsi, sparse-files, thinpool

I would like to shrink the space required by a thin volume used as a disk for a virtual machine (Windows). Unfortunately, the underlying disk is a USB-attached SSD and therefore mounting the NTFS filesystem and trying to use fstrim does not work (unsupported operation). How could I reduce the space used by this thin volume?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1255128/lvm-thinpool-thinvolume-free-blocks-reclaim-space

Comment: @user1133275 Won't work as underlying device does not support the operation